# Function of Values

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am using the `Mat_<float> aque(3,3);`

```
aque << .240 , .640 , .450
        ,0,0,0
        ,0,0,0
```

I want to turn it in to light blue , how I can adjust these values ? I want to know the function of these three values .240 , .640 , .450 in matrix , I know these all are presenting blue color but what are their functionalities what they all 3 values present ?

Comment: hi FLY, what are you trying to do with that Mat ?

Comment: @Berak my bro ,I want to transform it with the image to get the light bluish shade on image

Comment: berak , you may use the Aque filter in instagram i am trying to make that type of image with my program

Comment: sorry, absolutely apple-free household here ;)   (but i get, what you're trying now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just go and do your own  experiments ?

```
int f[9] = {24,64,45,0,0,0,0,0,0};  // initial trackbar pos
Mat filt(3,3,CV_32F); 
Mat img;

void onTrack(int,void*)
{
    float *p = filt.ptr<float>(0);
    for ( int i=0; i<9; i++ )
    {
        p[i] = float(f[i]) / 100;   // get it back to [0..1] range for the transform matrix
    }
    Mat out;
    cv::transform(img,out,filt);
    imshow("result",out);
}

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    img = imread("lena.jpg");
    namedWindow("result",0);
    namedWindow("sliders",0);
    createTrackbar("1","sliders",&f[0],100,onTrack);
    createTrackbar("2","sliders",&f[1],100,onTrack);
    createTrackbar("3","sliders",&f[2],100,onTrack);
    createTrackbar("4","sliders",&f[3],100,onTrack);
    createTrackbar("5","sliders",&f[4],100,onTrack);
    createTrackbar("6","sliders",&f[5],100,onTrack);
    createTrackbar("7","sliders",&f[6],100,onTrack);
    createTrackbar("8","sliders",&f[7],100,onTrack);
    createTrackbar("9","sliders",&f[8],100,onTrack);

    onTrack(0,0);
    waitKey();

    cerr << filt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

if you 're happy with the results, just divide each slider value by 100, and compose a filter matrix from that.

Comment: Still you didn't answer me why we use `3` values for blue , `3` for green and `3` for red ?

Comment: 3 values for blue: 1st: how much of the *original blue* intensity should go into the 'new' blue, 2nd: how much of the *original green* intensity should go into the 'new' blue, 3rd: how much of the *original red* intensity should go into the 'new' blue

Comment: by `orignal blue green and red` you mean the image which already contain that color , like the image on which we are apply algorithm already contain that values of red green and blue ? yea ?

Comment: think of it as a matrix-multiplication: new_pixel = mat * old_pixel

Comment: Can we use the same scenerio for the hue saturation and intensity ?

Comment: well, maths and the opencv api allow that. i just got no idea if it makes sense (it's up to you to decide that).

Comment: What if i want that the value of my orignal image display with that scrollbars , that the values which my image contain , is it posible